# Iterating over column to get unique values and getting the mean for each value

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the mean for heartdisease for the restingecg column using python. I believe my code is correct, for the most part. But what I can't figure out is how to only add that unique value to the ECG column in the resulting dataframe.

```
scores=[]
ecg=df_full_train.restingecg.unique()
for c in ecg:
    score=df_full_train[df_full_train.restingecg==c].heartdisease.mean()
    scores.append((ecg,score))

df_scores=pd.DataFrame(scores, columns=['ECG','Score'])

df_scores.head()
```

The above code produces this output.

```
    ECG                 Score
0   [LVH, Normal, ST]   0.519737
1   [LVH, Normal, ST]   0.511468
2   [LVH, Normal, ST]   0.657534
```

I want the ECG column output to look like this

```
LVH
Normal
ST
```

Comment: I guess what you need to do is `scores.append((c,score))`. instead of ecg

Comment: Oh duh! Thank you!